# React/JestJS/Enzyme: How to test for ref function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I'm running unit tests using Jest and Enzyme for this very simple component `render()`:

```
render() {
  return (<Input
    id='foo'
    ref={input => { this.refInput = input }}
  />)
}

it('should render Input', () => {
  wrapper = shallow(<Component />)
  expect(wrapper.find(Input)).toHaveLength(1)
})
```

I'm also using the coverage option of Jest and there I see, that the line

```
ref={input => { this.refInput = input }}
```

is not covered by my test. What do I have to do to get a full covered unit test for this sample component?

Comment: You might have to use `mount` for that

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The ref is attached to an instance of the component hence you will have to use [`mount`](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/mount.html) to get an instance of the component.

To test for the `ref`, add the following line

```
expect(wrapper.instance().refInput).toBeTruthy();
```

Final result:

```
render() {
  return (<Input
    id='foo'
    ref={input => { this.refInput = input }}
  />)
}

it('should render Input', () => {
  const wrapper = mount(<Component />);
  expect(wrapper.find(Input)).toHaveLength(1)
  expect(wrapper.instance().refInput).toBeTruthy();
})
```

Comment: This might be sufficient if you just want to test that the instance property is set. But it won't work if you want to test that ref callbacks with that specific function: (see https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)

```
function CustomTextInput(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <input ref={props.inputRef} />
    </div>
  );
}

class Parent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <CustomTextInput
        inputRef={el => this.inputElement = el}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The question was to get full coverage. Adding that test gave 100% coverage (I did test it). I don't get your comment. Explain yourself better with an answer?

Comment: Ideally, you want something like `expect(wrapper.find(Input).ref()).eq(wrapper.instance().props.inputRef)` assuming you are testing the functional component which is passing inputRef prop as the ref callback. See https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#exposing-dom-refs-to-parent-components Unfortunately, enzyme doesn't expose some something like `.ref()` api.

Comment: `expect(wrapper.instance().refInput).toBeInstanceOf(Input);` will be better.

Answer (score 7):

I solved the issue like this:

```
const ref = React.createRef();
const props = { register: jest.fn(params => ref), label: "label text", ...params };
let wrapper = mount(
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <Input {...props} />
    </ThemeProvider>
);
expect(wrapper.find(Entity).getElement().ref).toBe(ref);
```

I have entity component inside input which receives ref function.

Comment: exactly what I've needed. Thanks!